# Output of this code is not what I do expect. Where is the issue?

Tags: c, loops, nested

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int i=1, j=1;
    while(i++<=100)
    {
        while(j++<=200)
        {
            if(j==150)
                break;
            else
                printf(“%d%d\n”, i, j);
         }

      } 
 }
```

In output, I see outer loop just iterating, 2 and 3 times, but nothing further. I think the outer loop should iterate 100 times and the inner loop should iterate 200 times in each iteration of outer loop.

But it is not happening. Can anyone guide me on this?

I am using Dev C++ and taking a C-language course.

Comment: you don't reset `j = 0`. Once it goes past the 200 the inner `while` loop will not be entered, thus no output.

Comment: put a `printf` into problematic loop to see what happens (as a general rule)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int i=1, j=1;
    while(i++<=100)
    {
        while(j++<=200)
        {
            if(j==150)
                break;
            else
                printf(“%d%d\n”, i, j);
         }
         //don't forget to reset your j counter on every iteration of the outer loop.
         j=1;
      } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you are not resetting the `j` counter at the end of the inner while loop. As a result, the compiler will not enter the while loop once `j` exceeds 200, because it is never reset to 1. Reset `j` to 1 after the end of your inner while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 1, j = 1;
    while(i++ <= 100)
    {
        while(j++ <= 200)
        {
            if (j == 150)
                break;
            else
                printf(“%d%d\n”, i, j);
         }

         // You need to reset j after your inner while loop finishes running.
         j = 1;
     } 
}
```

Comment: In the next iteration of the outer loop, j should enter in the inner loop until the conditions satisfied. Not? What thing is stopping it from entering inner loop? When inner loop will reach 201 in the third iteration of the outer loop, control should come to outer loop because inner loop condition doesn't satisfy at 201. So in the next iteration of outer loop i.e. 4, control should enter into the inner loop because it is now 1 and not 201.

Comment: When the loop is exited from the while condition and not from break, it should be reset automatically and in this case, inner loop was terminating from while. So what is stopping outer loop to enter inner loop when j is already reset.

Comment: @JavaidAkhtar It will iterate the first time till j reaches 150. Then at the second increment of the outer loop, it will become 151, so the while loop will continue to run till 200. Now, in your code, you do not reset `j` so as soon as `j = 201`, the inner loop will not run at any increment of the outer loop. The counter `j`won't reset automatically.

Comment: Also, just some advice for: [__What you should do if someone accepts your answer__](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) since you are new to StackOverflow. You can accept an answer by checking the tickmark next to it.